# How to add an editable TreeViewItem with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a program that exibits the file system content (files & folders) with code.
each file or folder reflected by a TreeViewItem.
i want to able editing each TreeViewItem from the UI.

Comment: So what is your question? Could you provide some code with what you already tried?

Comment: Very good! You almost achieved your goal. Wanting something is very important. Now you only have to implement it. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, quite easy.  Here is an example...

```
                <TreeView x:Name="treeView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Background="Beige">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Files" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
                            <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem>

                </TreeView>
```

Code behind...

```
    public interface INamedObject
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class FileObject : INamedObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    };
    public class FolderObject : ObservableCollection<INamedObject>, INamedObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    };
    FolderObject _root = new FolderObject() { Name = "root" };
    public FolderObject Root
    {
        get
        {
            return _root;
        }
    }
```